# Emission and Transparant mixture works in 3D View but not in Render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders

I'm a bit new to cycles shaders, so I'm going about this a bit blindly.

I've tried mixing a few shaders, and it works in the rendered viewport, but not in the full render.

I'm trying to make spaceship thrusters. It should start emitting  brightly, and then gradually fade to transparent. I've tried both particles, and volumes, but neither worked well for me.

This is my material:

[image: Shader program]

And here is the (expected) 3D View rendered result (left) and the actual (incorrect) rendered result (right):

[image: Shader output]

**[The .blend file](http://www.filedropper.com/test-neilos)**

**EDIT**: I was able to get it to work by switching to CPU from GPU.

Comment: Is it possible you could upload your .blend?

Comment: give me a moment and I'll make a simplified blend that exhibits the problem.

Comment: @gandalf3 Interestingly when I tried to create a new blend showing the problem I couldn't reproduce it (it worked). But I cannot get my blend to work so I created a cut down version of my blend and uploaded that (see the link at the top of the post). There is probably some setting I have not set. I canabalised another blend file to create this one so some artifact from that surely remains which is causing the problem.

Comment: On a slight tangent. If I wanted to copy certain objects from my scene to a new blend, what's the easiest way to do this?

Comment: I was able to solve it by setting the render device to CPU instead of GPU, ,shouldn't I be able to render transparency on the surface shader using the GPU?

Comment: Yes, you definitely should. It works for me though, even with the lamp output node. There might be a bug here somewhere..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lamp output node is not intended for use with surfaces, as a matter of fact I'm surprised it worked at all in viewport render.

It works fine for me if you replace it with a material output node:

[image]